# Working with tables in a custom form recognizer model C#

Tags: c#, azure-form-recognizer

I created a custom model in the Form Recognizer Studio. I'm able to analysis forms I have in a blob container. The field results outputs to the console just how I want them to. However, I'm unable to output the correct results for the tables.

The form I'm using has 6 tables. However, I trained the model only on the one table I care about. The line of code below:

DocumentTable table = (DocumentTable)result.Tables[1];

takes an int 0 - 5 for the 6 table identified. I want it to output only my table and not the 6 tables identified.

I'm pasting my code below. Please let me know what to put in the bolded section to get my trained table to print out.

```
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Xml;
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;
```

```
string endpoint = "https://XXXXXXXXXX";
string key = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential); 

string modelId = "ScanTest";
Uri fileUri = new Uri("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pdf");
AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, modelId, fileUri);
AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

foreach (AnalyzedDocument document in result.Documents)
{
    //Console.WriteLine($"Document of type: {document.DocumentType}");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DocumentField> fieldKvp in document.Fields)
    {
        string fieldName = fieldKvp.Key;
        DocumentField field = fieldKvp.Value;

        Console.WriteLine($"Field '{fieldName}': ");

        Console.WriteLine($"  Content: '{field.Content}'");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Confidence: '{field.Confidence}'");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Confidence: '{field.FieldType}'");

       
        if (fieldName == "WageTable")
        {
            **DocumentTable table = (DocumentTable)result.Tables[1];**

            Console.WriteLine($"  Table {fieldName} has {table.RowCount} rows and {table.ColumnCount} columns.");

                foreach (DocumentTableCell cell in table.Cells)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"    Cell ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex}) has kind '{cell.Kind}' and content: '{cell.Content}'.");
                }
          }
     }
}
```

```
So, please let me know how to refer to my table instead of all of the tables identified.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string endpoint = "https://XXXXXXXXXX";
string key = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential); 

string modelId = "ScanTest";
Uri fileUri = new Uri("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pdf");
AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, modelId, fileUri);
AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

   foreach (var cell in result.Tables[1].Cells)
    {
    enter code here
        Console.WriteLine($"  Cell[{cell.RowIndex}][{cell.ColumnIndex}] has content '{cell.Content}' with kind '{cell.Kind}'");
    }
```

Comment: Okay - I just played with this again. It looks like they fixed the issue. The object results.Tables[0] is now the table that has been trained.

Comment: Actually, it is still screwed up. It still returns all of the tables identified not just the trained tables.

Comment: However, the table does show up in the JSON file. So I guess that is the work around.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?